# Expressões estranhas em PHP

Tags: php, característica-linguagem, estilo-de-codificação, sintaxe, certificado-digital

Alguém explica porque isso:

```
<?php

   $world = _("World"); 
   $str = <<<EOF
   <p>Hello</p>
   <p>$world</p>
EOF;
    echo $str;

?>
```

gera isso:

```
Hello

World
```

sem erro?

o que seria isso `<<<`, `EOF`, `<p>$world</p>`, `_("World");`. Enfim queria entender o que são essas coisas que nunca vi desenvolvendo em no dia a dia [PHP](http://www.php.net/)

**Podemos definir qualquer coisa depois de `<<< EOF`?**

Seria correto desenvolver `PHP` com `html` utilizando isso? 
se sim porque? se não porque ?

**Exemplo**, ao invés disso:

```
echo "<table><tr><td>".$titulo."</td></tr></table>";
```

ou disso:

```
<table><tr><td><?php echo $titulo ?></td></tr></table>
```

Escrever isso:

```
//tabela
$minha_tabela = <<<EOF
<table>
 <tr>
  <td>titulo e $titulo</td>
 <tr>
<table>    

EOF;
//apenas dando esse echo mostro minha tabela aonde eu quero
echo $minha_tabela;
```

Comment: Quanto ao `_('world');` ou pode ser uma função definida pelo usuário com esse nome ou é a extensão para adicionar tradução ao site chamada [gettext](http://php.net/manual/en/book.gettext.php)

Comment: ainda tem o <p>$word</p> sem echo

Comment: o `<<<QUALQUERCOISA $variable QUALQUERCOISA;` vai concatenar as variáveis que você passar quando você utilizar o `echo`. É o mesmo que `sprintf("Hello %s", $world)` ou ainda `echo "Hello $world";`

Comment: O `<p>$word</p>` esta dentro do EOF, logo não é expressão do PHP e sim HTML salvo dentro do valor da variavel

Comment: Ser correto ou não é muito relativo. Na verdade esses `<<<QUALQUER_COISA` é só mais uma forma de imprimir múltiplas linhas com uma interpolação/concatenação de variáveis. https://pastebin.com/xHn9bm2q . Eu uso dessa forma quando faço algo em `cli`.